# Finding the bearing with reference to North of a position having GPS latitude and longitude

Tags: gps, gis, distance, heading, bearing

I am very basic question. Can we find the bearing i.e. angle with respect to North of a coordinate i.e. having GPS lat long of single point without any other sensors. I searched but everywhere it is like finding the bearing between two points, I want to know whether can we find bearing of single point without knowing the direction.

Secondly if we move our angle to some degrees, can we again find the new bearing?

Any reference or link to any material if available please help.

Comment: If you are in a single point, you can be facing any direction, so it doesn’t make much sense to define bearing for a single point. You could assume the second point as the coordinates of the North Pole and calculate bearing as usual, but I’m not sure if this is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

The bearing is an angle. Angle is a figure *between* two directions or rays with common origin (note it is not between two points, but between two rays). The bearing is angle between (1) direction from some point A to North and (2) direction from same point A to another point B.

So yes, you need two points to define bearing. While first direction (to North) is defined by a single point, defining second direction requires another reference point.

Comment: If we fix the one of latitude to 90 degree, can we have find the angle and what we will call that bearing with reference to north at what direction?